# How to add a 2% burn and 2% redistribution to holders?

Tags: solidity

I've been compiling a project on remix.ethereum.org and would like to launch a crypto that has a burn on each transaction.  Is it possible to add in just a few lines of code into the token contract that would burn 2% of supply with each transaction and redistributes 2% of the supply to holders of the token (ie: sender sends 100 token, 96 arrive with recipient, 2 are burned and 2 are automatically redistributed proportionally between all other holders of the token)?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it is not trivial. This contract https://github.com/safemoonprotocol/Safemoon.sol/blob/main/Safemoon.sol has some ideas that can help you.